# Certain tags are totally empty when you select them?

Tags: bug, status-completed, tags

I hope I have come to the right place to for this kind of question.

When I click certain tags I know have questions in them they are displays as 0 questions. For example I clicked the as3 tag which I have as an interesting tag. I know there are questions in there.

Same thing with actionscript3, totally empty. Even if you click through stats, newest, featured, hot, votes and active - it says 0 questions. BUT when I click the flex tag, it shows the questions and then if I click as3 in the "related tags" box it shows all the questions in as3.

I am just being totally stupid and doing something wrong or have all the questions just disapeared in the "interesting tags" section?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe the list of tags (and their question counts) is updated as a regular job, whereas the set of questions is queried "live" when you click on a tag.

So if someone has been retagging `as3` to `actionscript3` for example, the tag will still appear for a while, but without any questions when you click on it.

Comment: I was going to answer this with the guess that it was due to a tag-merge and the totals didn't refresh yet but I was unsure if that merge operation had actually taken place. Based on what Joel C says, that appears to be the case.

Comment: Thank you, Jon. Makes perfect sense

Comment: Which reminds me... we must take away that spare multi[-]threading badge of yours at some point!

Comment: Nooo! I'm sure Jeff mentioned that once badges were awarded they couldn't be removed...

Comment: Well, at one point there was a "recalc badges" button in the moderator tools; I never used it, and it seems to have disappeared... so I can't steal it back ;-p But Jeff has noticed it, so don't be shocked if it evaporates one night...

Comment: Now the truth comes out - it's a conspiracy to steal my precious badges!

Comment: I can imagine you as the wee Leprechaun from the Lucky charms adverts. "They're after me badges!"

Comment: Damn, he's onto us. Jon! look over there! somebody is misquoting the C# spec! And they've called it C#.NET 2008 3.5! [quick everyone - grab what you can before he notices]

Answer (score 1):

It looks like those tags were merged under the new 'actionscript-3' tag.  New questions should now only this tag, and not the other two.

You can find more info of these mass-retags here:
https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2850/the-great-tagging-reorg

Comment: Yes, you are totally right. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

There has been a lot of re-tagging lately. Where possible, I've tried to use the tools to migrate the data such that the old tag is deleted, but this has not always been possible.

Apologies for any confusion.