# Empty tags with no questions

Tags: discussion

With reference to the question [Certain tags are totally empty when you select them?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4718/certain-tags-are-totally-empty-when-you-select-them), I just spotted that there are some empty tags, [do-my-homework](/questions/tagged/do-my-homework) and [domyjobforme](/questions/tagged/domyjobforme), which don't have any questions under them. I tried proposing a tag synonym that would remap [do-my-homework](/questions/tagged/do-my-homework) to [homework](/questions/tagged/homework), but it doesn't work - any ideas please?

Comment: The empty tags will be removed automatically after 24 hours by the system, don't worry about them

Comment: Where did you see those tags? Browsing to non existent tag will always bring empty page e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/I-do-not-exist however those tags won't appear anywhere.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As Yi noted, tags with no questions get deleted automatically after a bit.  Synonyms should really only be made for tags that are useful; crap questions should be closed or fixed and not retagged.

Comment: Ok fair enough :)