# Empty tags (with no questions) are not deleted

Tags: support, tags, tag-pruning

For example in [this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/112519/empty-tags-with-no-questions), it was said that empty tags are deleted after 24 hours. This seems to not be the case for tags which have a synonym or an info. Examples: [works-on-my-machine](/questions/tagged/works-on-my-machine) [calculation](/questions/tagged/calculation)

Comment: The [tag:calculation] tag had a synonym on it which prevented it from being destroyed properly. I've removed it.

Comment: This seems to be a post describing in detail the issue mentioned by @animuson: [Auto-delete orphaned tag synonyms](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/317928).