# Auto-delete orphaned tag synonyms

Tags: feature-request, bug, tag-synonyms, tag-pruning

I recently encountered [this question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/376283/what-are-tags-without-questions-with-existing-synonym) on MSO, where a user asks about why certain tags appear in the tag overview page.

This issue is caused by a synonym that redirects users to a non-existent tag.

I've created [this SEDE query](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/922774/orphaned-tag-synonyms), and on Stack Overflow alone, a total of 60 approved synonyms exist that point to tags that don't exist. On other sites, I expect orphaned synonyms will exist too.

These synonyms are still functional: they show up in the tag page, when searching for it you still get redirected, and if you try to use it in a new question, you will get a prompt if you want to create the synonym target (if you have enough rep to create tags). Also, if the synonym has a very similar name to the target tag, attempts to create the target tag [will fail with a confusing error message](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/371843/confusing-error-message-when-trying-to-add-a-blocked-tag).

Could we destroy all synonyms too when destroying tags? Or add a separate cleanup script for synonyms?

<sub>Not sure if should be a feature request or bug report, feel free to retag.</sub>

Comment: This question was referenced [here](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/64770793#64770793). I think it's an interesting question and I'm surprised that we don't have any visible comments or answers on it.