# Tag synonym persists even after parent tag is deleted

Tags: feature-request, bug, tags, tag-synonyms

On Music Fans SE, the tag `milesdavis` was merged with the tag `miles-davis` on [May 27 '15](https://musicfans.stackexchange.com/tags/synonyms). At some point, the parent tag was removed from all existing questions, so it was auto-deleted. But, the synonym is still present in the [list of tags](https://musicfans.stackexchange.com/tags?page=4&tab=name). Clicking on the synonym redirects to the page of the parent tag.

Ideally, one would expect all the synonyms to be deleted when the parent tag is deleted.

- Can we have that when a parent tag is (auto) deleted, so are all its synonyms?
- In the meantime, is there anything that a user (or moderator) can do to remove such tags that are in limbo?

I notice that a similar feature-request / bug report was made [earlier](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/317928/auto-delete-orphaned-tag-synonyms), but that was over a year ago and there has been no response on that question, so I hope it's alright to resurrect this issue with a new question.

Comment: @SonictheAnonymousHedgehog I have mentioned that question in the body of my post.

Comment: Please note that per [policy](/a/47635/377214) (see also the last section of [this](/a/10844/377214)), this question should be closed as a duplicate; the fact that the prior request never received a response isn't relevant for the purposes of policy. If you want to get a prior unhandled request implemented, the proper way is to [get attention for the original report](/q/306397).

Comment: @SonictheAnonymousHedgehog Thank you for the links, I understand the policy on Meta now.