# "(0 answers)" shows up as "( answers)" in new duplicate post notice

Tags: bug, status-completed, design, duplicate-questions, post-notices

[This question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/342730/313042) of mine was voted to be closed as a duplicate, and I received a banner at the top asking

> **Does this answer your question?**
>
> [Auto-delete orphaned tag synonyms](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/317928/auto-delete-orphaned-tag-synonyms) ( answers)

I presume the weird space in "( answers)" is because it's supposed to mention the number of answers that the suggested duplicate has, but in this case the suggested duplicate has 0 answers, which is causing some trouble.

Here's a screenshot of the entire banner:
[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This should be fixed now. The duplicate notice for post owners should correctly show answer counts for all potential duplicate questions.

Comment: Perhaps its worthwile to consider 0 answers as a special case. Seeing the post notice states *"that may solve your problem"* and *"Does this answer your question"* which both are unlikely if a question is unanswered. Perhaps we could emphasise more that it has already been asked, instead of emphasising that answers can be found in an unanswered question.