# Rephrase text for possible duplicate with no answers

Tags: feature-request, duplicate-questions, unanswered-questions, wording

One more time I got a possible duplicate notice on my question. This time there's no answer on the suggested question:

> [image: Some community members have suggested a similar question that may solve your problem. Does this answer your question? Minor alignment issue Yes in Activity page Impact section's tooltip (0 answers)]

I know the duplicate mechanic on SE, but completely disagree with the current wording. How could the post with no answers answer my question? Can we just improve the wording to reflect that fact that closing as duplicate is for the same question, but not for finding the answer?

Related [comment](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/342732/0-answers-shows-up-as-answers-in-new-duplicate-post-notice#comment1148695_342981) was found:

> Perhaps its worthwile to consider 0 answers as a special case. Seeing the post notice states "that may solve your problem" and "Does this answer your question" which both are unlikely if a question is unanswered. Perhaps we could emphasise more that it has already been asked, instead of emphasising that answers can be found in an unanswered question.

Comment: I think it still may be true, it’s not necessarily the case that a question with 0 answers doesn’t have an “answer” in the comments, or a helpful link in the question, or the question includes enough context that it alone does answer the new question.

Comment: This is mostly a Meta problem. On main sites, a question needs to have an upvotes/accepted answer in order for users to vote to close duplicates against it, unless the authors are the same. (Moderators can bypass that but instantly close duplicates, so this banner doesn't appear.)

Comment: @AaronBertrand While your case does happen sometimes, the vast majority of close votes I cast against unanswered questions is when the same bug report or feature request has been previously filed. Such closures don't really point to a solution that would solve the author's problem, but rather just serve to consolidate multiple requests for the same thing into a single question. Also, the only case where this shows up on main sites is where the question was posted by the same user, where 90% of the time it's where the author is trying to get attention for their older unanswered question.

Comment: @Sonic Sure, I'm just saying it's not false 100% of the time. And on main sites I think I agree with Laurel, it shouldn't be happening where a question is closed as a duplicate of another question that has 0 answers. Seems much more relevant to bug reports here than anything on main. Anyway, this is another example of something that maybe isn't the hill worth dying on. :-)