# Confusing error message when trying to add a blocked(?) tag

Tags: support, tags, wording, blocked-tags

A while ago, I was trying to edit a question on Web Applications, but got a rather confusing error message:

> The tag [charts] is too similar to [charts]. If you think this new tag should be allowed, discuss it on meta.

I *think* the system is trying to tell me that the [charts] tag is blocked, but my initial reaction was "I must have made a spelling error" (and the second one "there's a zero-width space playing tricks on me"). Is my guess right, and if so, can the message be improved?

[image: "charts" written in the tags box in an attempt to edit it in, with the aforementioned error message]

Comment: So, would you like to discuss whether [charts] is really too close to [charts]? Honestly, I don't think it is.

Comment: Its similarity is off the charts...

Comment: It's an uncharted synonym.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The system is not referencing blocked tags here - there is no rule blocking such a tag. The error is a result of an odd situation that has occurred on Web Apps.

Currently, there is a synonym that exists for [chart](/questions/tagged/chart) that directs it to [charts](/questions/tagged/charts), but the [charts](/questions/tagged/charts) tag itself has since been deleted and no longer exists, requiring it to be created again. However, because there exists a synonym, the system thinks the [chart](/questions/tagged/chart) tag "exists" even in a fake way and the system does not allow non-moderators to create new tags that differ only by hyphens and pluralizations.

It is seeing the [chart](/questions/tagged/chart) tag synonym, preventing the creation of [charts](/questions/tagged/charts) due to similarly, and then the error message is reading out [charts](/questions/tagged/charts) twice because the lookup is being redirected to the plural form making the message very confusing.

Simplest solution: delete the synonym that is no longer useful.

Comment: OK, I didn't expect that ... I'll rewrite my question to a [tag:support] one, keeping your answer valid of course :)